# Scaling "node distance" in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Well, here's another TikZ question; this time, I have no idea how to find an answer.  I would like to give all my nodes with relative coordinates:

```
\node (A) {A};
\node (B) [right = of A] {B};
```

using the `positioning` library.  The distance is `node distance`.  Unfortunately, it appears that passing the option `scale = <factor>` to `{tikzpicture}` does not have the desired effect on this distance; in fact, it does nothing.  How can I give unit-free distances with relative coordinates?

Comment: Good question!  A little experimenting shows that the instructions given via the "positioning" library are considered to be transformations _of the node_.  They therefore are not usually affected by external transformations.  As an example, consider putting `rotate=180` on your example: `B` is _still_ to the right of `A`.  You can make external transformations apply to a node by using the key `transform shape` but then they apply to the node shape as well, which is not what is wanted.  So there needs to be a key which says "apply the external transformation to the position but not the shape".

Comment: Well, since you bring it up, there's another place this occurs: using `fit`.  This will transform a node so that it has both the correct size and the correct position to contain some given nodes.  But what if I want to make a bunch of "containers" which are spaced enough to keep their contents apart?  I have to draw the contents BEFORE the containers so that I can use `fit` to get the size, but then I can't reposition the containers.  Nested `{tikzpicture}` seems to be the only way to get nodes within nodes like this.  So, it would be nice if one could separate shape and position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Method 1** Apparently you don't have to give units to the `node distance` key.  If you don't, it seems to take them as coordinates.  So this scales the node distance to three times the default unit length, and the default unit length is the same as the default node distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[node distance=3]
\node (A) {A};
\node (B) [right = of A] {B};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Method 2** *after comments, consensus is that this is the preferred method* It's possible to plot a point, read its coordinates, and set the node distance to that.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=3]
\pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointxy{1}{1}};
\pgfgetlastxy{\vx}{\vy}
\begin{scope}[node distance=\vy and \vx] % strange syntax here
\node (A) {A};
\node (B) [right = of A] {B};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Edit** improvement that doesn't enlarge the bounding box invisibly from Andrew Stacey's comment.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference with the first method.  Did you?

Comment: Also, where does `\pgfgetlastxy` come from?  I get an error trying that.  It would be very useful...

Comment: (1) Yes, and (2) section 76.6 of the PGF 2.10 manual.  Sounds like we might have different versions.

Comment: @Ryan (and Matthew): The first method doesn't work: if I add `rotate=180` then the nodes stay the same but everything else rotates.  The second method *does* work.  I'm using the latest (or nearly latest) pgf and it's in there.  The file that the command is defined in is dated 2010/04/09 (presumably the last commit of that file to the VCS) so a version more recent than that will do.

Comment: Oh, but you should fix it so that the node (v) isn't involved in computing bounding boxes.

Comment: Here's a fix that removes the node: `\pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointxy{1}{1}}
\pgfgetlastxy{\vx}{\vy}`.

Comment: I just upgraded to pgf2.10 and I'm still not seeing a difference with the first method.

Comment: As Groucho said, "Who are you going to believe, me or your lying eyes?" :-)) Here's my [complete document](http://pastebin.com/uPez1GdH) and [file list](http://pastebin.com/SRvjUz2C).

Comment: I'm apparently stuck with pgf2.00 since Ubuntu doesn't have very fast updates; I will see if I can manage to install 2.10 by hand and try this out again.

Comment: @Ryan: the definition of `\pgfgetlastxy` is very simple: `\def\pgfgetlastxy#1#2{\edef#1{\the\pgf@x}\edef#2{\the\pgf@y}}` so you could copy that in to your preamble (with the appropriate `\makeatletter`s).  However, I recommend updating - it's a painless procedure.

Comment: @Matthew: I just downloaded your example.  What I see with your *first* bit of code is that the `xscale` and the `node distance` don't interact.  Setting the `node distance` to `3` and the `xscale` to `3` should (morally!) to set the separation to `9` but it doesn't, it's at `3`.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh yes, I agree with that.  I guess we were talking about different things "working" :-)

Comment: @Matthew: Now I understand.  You never claimed that the two effects augmented each other, just that this achieved the same effect.  I do think that that's a bit confusing in your answer and that my misreading isn't unreasonable; particularly the linking text "Another way to do this ...".  It seems, from Ryan's comments here, that the second way answers his question so may I gently suggest that you emphasise that part of your answer?

Comment: Okay, upgraded and the second example indeed works.  Thanks Matthew, Andrew!

Comment: @Andrew: no problem.  I edited.  I thought about putting the second answer first but then that makes the comments confusing.  If you feel it can be further clarified, please edit further.