# extracting coordinates from "position" pair in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I think I have a simple problem but somehow I'm unable to find any solution:
I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1 , auto,swap]
\foreach \pos/\name in { {(9,7)}/a, {(6,6)}/b, {(9,5)}/c }{
    \node (\name) at \pos {\pos[1]};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It obviously doesn't work as intended because `\pos[1]` produces labels like `(9,7)[1]`:)

Is there a simple way to extract the first coordinate from `\pos`? So that labels of node would be 9,6,9 respectively?

And I would like to avoid changing entire loop to something like

```
\foreach \posX/\posY/\name in { {9/7/a}, {6/6/b}, {9/5/c} }{...}
```

Comment: leave the slashes outside the braces e.g. `{(9,7)}/a`

Comment: You can extract the coordinates using `let...in` syntax, but unfortunately you'll get the result in points, not in the "unit-less" integers you specified them.

Comment: FWIW, you can use `let` if you replace your `\node` command for, say, `\path let \p1 = \pos in node (\name) at \pos {\x1}` to see what @JLDiaz meant. I think you might just have to change your loop, since then the solution would be trivial.

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5525/575) for a way to extract coordinates from a point *already* plotted (I know that's not what you're asking).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extracting the numbers you put in a pair of coordinates is not possible, because tikz tranforms those "unitless" coordinates into actual points (taking into account the `scale`, `x` and `y` options, etc).

The syntax `let...in` allows you to get those coordinates, but usually only for using them as part of the calculations to get other coordinates, but not for printing them. Trying to do so:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1 , auto,swap]
\foreach \pos/\name in { {(9,7)}/a, {(6,6)}/b, {(9,5)}/c }{
    \path let \p1=\pos in node (\name) at \pos {\x1};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Produces unsatisfactory results:

> [image: Bad]

For this particular case, instead of trying to get the X coordinate from tikz, you can try the following hack, which extracts the first number before the comma directly from the `\pos` macro:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1 , auto,swap]
\def\getX(#1,#2){#1}
\foreach \pos/\name in { {(9,7)}/a, {(6,6)}/b, {(9,5)}/c }{
    \node (\name) at \pos {\expandafter\getX\pos};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in what you want:

> [image: Good]

Comment: I was hacking away at a solution with `xstring`, but this is much nicer. :)

Comment: `\foreach \pos/\name[evaluate={\tX=\expandafter\getX\pos}] in {(9,7)/a, (6,6)/b, (9,5)/c} \node (\name) at \pos {\tX};` might be helpful if you want to use the values repeatedly. (Or, of course, `\edef\tX{\expandafter\getX\pos}`.)