# tikz, positioning library: node distances in scaled pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I do find it arkward that numbers without dimension in the shifting part of the keys from the positioning library are not scaled. I can retrieve the unit vector and use it in the values but I do find the syntax user unfriendly. Is there some good way to tell tikz to interpret "below right=3 and 3" as 3*scaled xvector instead of 3*xvector?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointxy{1}{1}};
\pgfgetlastxy{\xvec}{\yvec}
\tikzset{node distance=\xvec*1 and \yvec*1}


\coordinate (C) at (1,1);
\draw[red,fill] (C) circle (5pt);
\node[below=of C] {no shifting part};
\node[below right=3 and 3,anchor=base west] (A) at (C) {no cm};
\node[below right=3cm and 3cm,anchor=base east] (D) at (C) {cm};
\node[below right=\xvec*3 and \yvec*3,anchor=south] (B) at (C) {scaled};
\draw[red](C)--(A.base west);
\end{tikzpicture}



\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3,show background rectangle]
\pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointxy{1}{1}};
\pgfgetlastxy{\xvec}{\yvec}
\tikzset{node distance=\xvec*1 and \yvec*1}


\coordinate (C) at (1,1);
\draw[red,fill] (C) circle (5pt);
\node[below=of C] {no shifting part}; %ok
%This should work like in the last node:
\node[below right=3 and 3,anchor=base west] (A) at (C) {no cm}; %not ok
\node[below right=3cm and 3cm,anchor=base east] (D) at (C) {cm}; %ok
\node[below right=\xvec*3 and \yvec*3,anchor=south] (B) at (C) {scaled}; %ok 
\draw[red](C)--(A.base west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you prefer `below right=<distance or factor>` and `at (C)` over `below right=<distance or factor> of C` (whereas the latter does set an appropriate anchor for the reference point on C in case of a node with a shape)? My [`positioning-plus`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex) (update on the way) helps with the factoring. What should the last example yield? Where should the new node lie exactly?

Comment: To extend on that, as `node distance` is for node (aka labels for a diagram) placement, they are usually not considered for transformations defined outside of the node. `transform shape` changes that (which is not a solution here). See also [Scaling "node distance" in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5506) and Andrew’s comment.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I had seen the "scaling node distance" question and I understand the *source* of the problem but the solution there doesn't adapt to the shifting part. In my current problem I'm using the `at (C)` syntax but imho such a change should adapt to `of C` to as everything else is simply confusing. And while pondering about the problem: The best would be if users could choose if scaling is adapted or not, e.g. `below right=s3 and s3`, perhaps even with an option argument `= s[0.8]3 and s[0.5]3`.

Comment: As scaling is one example of a transformation, what would be the required behavior if the scope was rotated or slanted (or some combination of shifting, scaling, rotating or slanting)? I guess what is needed is some option to concatenate the transformation matrix for positioning only (otherwise `transform shape` gets the position right but also applies the transform matrix to the node's appearance).

Comment: @MarkWibrow: I'm only interested in scaling. If a picture with some markers/nodes is copied to another document and needs to be scaled a bit the node distances (as give by the shifting parts) should scale to. I don't expect that this always works without some manual adaptions - there will certainly be nodes that need to be shifted to avoid overprinting but this less fuss than having to adapt a lot of absolute values.

Answer (score 10):

I worked a little bit with my [`positioning-plus`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex) library which already contained a way to factor the stored values of `node distance` via

```
<direction>=<y-factor> and <x-factor>:of <reference>
```

which would already work for your examples with `node distance=1 and 1` as

```
below right=3 and 3:of C
```

or as

```
below right=3:of C
```

I added a small fix so that it also works without a reference, i.e. `below right=3 and 3:`.

The colon `:` is used as a separator for the scale factors. Technically it works to say `2 and 3:2cm and 3cm of <reference>`, whether that has any advantage over `4cm and 9cm of <reference>`, I don’t think so.

A syntax with a prepended with `s` seems to complicated to parse.

---

There is also the key `node distance transformation` (default: `true`) that activates a transformation for the positioning keys (similar to `transform shape` for nodes). Of course, any transformation will applied then (`rotate`, etc.).

I am not so experiences with PGF transformation and find them rather confusing sometimes so I don’t if this is the right/best way.

By the way, if you only want to scale the *xy* coordinate system, you can also use `x=.3cm, y=.3cm` for a scale of `.3` of the default coordinate system. However, this depends on your use-case and why you apply the scaling in the first place.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning-plus,backgrounds}
\tikzset{l/.style={
  label={[fill,circle,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+2pt,label=right:{#1}]center:}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded, node distance=1 and 1]
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\coordinate[l=ref] (C) at (1,1);
\coordinate[below right=1 and 1:,l={1 and 1}] (f1) at (C);
\coordinate[below right=3 and 2:,l={3 and 2}] (f2) at (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3, gridded, node distance=1 and 1,
                                             node distance transformation=true]
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\coordinate[l=ref] (C) at (1,1);
\coordinate[below right=1 and 1:,l={1 and 1}] (f1) at (C);
\coordinate[below right=3 and 2:,l={3 and 2}] (f2) at (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (not to scale)

[image][image]

Comment: This works (but not with french), but imho the syntax is a bit confusing - the colon looks a bit lost -- and you have to think about setting up the node-distance keys. I doubt that my users will find it natural. Currently I'm considering to define a function "unit" (which calculates the length of (1,0) and to propose the syntax `below right=3*unit and 3*unit`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The parsing can be done for both catcodes (similar things are done with `label`/`pin`). The colon wouldn’t look that lost if you’d use it with `of C` (but we can use `*`). — Either way, it seems I am missing your actual goal. I thought you want to give a factor for the values stored in `node distance` that is applied when given *and* scaling (transformation) via `scale` etc. Obviously the `1 and 1` factor is non-sense. You could just do `=of C` then. Maybe `positioning` is not the right approach?

Comment: Sorry that I confused you with the node distance: It is only there to change the distance of the node with `below=of C`. But I also want that the node which uses a shifting part (`below=3 of C`) gets nearer to C if the tikzpicture is scaled, so that they don't fall outside the picture. Your code is doing it fine but I need a syntax that is understable without a long description.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, you can use the `node distance transformation` key with the usual syntax, too: `below=3 of C` would be transformed just as well. The part before `:` scales the node distance (if no distance is given between `:` and `of`). The default for `node distance=1cm` (or `1cm and 1cm`?).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how desirable this answer is since it involves internal stuff, but essentially a key `scale positioning` is provided, which if `true` interrupts the usual positioning mechanism, extract the scaling from the transformation matrix and applies it to the positioning values before continuing as usual.

Odd things may happen if transformations other than scaling are applied, however.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter

\let\tikz@lib@place@handle@original=\tikz@lib@place@handle@
\def\tikz@lib@place@handle@alternative#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  % Get transform entries
  \pgfgettransformentries\tikz@a\tikz@b\tikz@c\tikz@d\tikz@e\tikz@f%
  % Get scale
  \pgfpoint{sqrt(\tikz@a*\tikz@a+\tikz@b*\tikz@b)*(\tikz@a<0 ? -1 : 1)}%
    {sqrt(\tikz@c*\tikz@c+\tikz@d*\tikz@d)*(\tikz@d<0 ? -1 : 1)}%
  \pgf@x=#3\pgf@x%
  \pgf@y=#4\pgf@y%
  \edef\tikz@lib@x{\pgfmath@tonumber\pgf@x}%
  \edef\tikz@lib@y{\pgfmath@tonumber\pgf@y}%
  \tikz@lib@place@handle@original{#1}{#2}{\tikz@lib@x}{\tikz@lib@y}{#5}{#6}%
}

\newif\iftikz@lib@place@scale@positioning
\tikzset{%
  scale positioning/.code={%
    \csname tikz@lib@place@scale@positioning#1\endcsname%
    \iftikz@lib@place@scale@positioning%
      \let\tikz@lib@place@handle@=\tikz@lib@place@handle@alternative%
    \else%
      \let\tikz@lib@place@handle@=\tikz@lib@place@handle@original%
    \fi%
  },
  scale positioning/.default=true,
  % Define special keys...
  below right'/.style={scale positioning, below right={#1}}%
  % ...more needed
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, 
  every node/.style={shape=circle},
  every pin edge/.style={<-}, 
  every pin/.style={shape=rectangle},
  mark/.style args={#1 at #2 with #3}{
   draw=#3, dotted,
   pin={[pin edge=#3, #3]#2:#1}
  }]

\fill [blue, opacity=0.25] (0,0) rectangle(5,3);

\coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (0,3);  

\draw [blue, <->] (3,0) -- (C);


\node [below right=3cm and 3cm of C, mark=cm at 260 with blue] {}; 
\node [below right=3 and 3 of C,  mark=vec at 280 with blue] {}; 

\begin{scope}[scale=0.3]

\coordinate [label=left:$C^\prime$] (C') at (0,3);  
\draw [red, <->] (3,0) -- (C');
\fill [red, opacity=0.25] (0,0) rectangle (5,3);

\node [below right=3cm and 3cm of C', mark=cm at 260 with red] {}; 
\node [below right=3 and 3 of C', mark=vec at 280 with red] {}; 

\node [below right=3cm and 3cm of C', dash phase=3.75pt, mark=cm at 220 with green] {}; 

% Scale one positioning using special key.
\node [below right'=3 and 3 of C', dash phase=3.75pt, mark=vec at 320 with green] {};

% Scale everything in a scope.
%
% NB. scale positioning can be used in path options 
% but *must* come before the positioning specification.
\begin{scope}[scale positioning]
\node [below right=3cm and 3cm of C',  mark=cm at 280 with orange] {};
\node [below right=3 and 3 of C',  mark=vec at 260 with orange] {};
\end{scope} 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `below right'` seems to do what I want. But if I use it (I'm not quite sure if I should overwrite internal commands in this case) I will certainly use another name which is easier to spot.